# Angularjs ajax request in Symfony2 and Doctrine json response with relationships

Tags: json, angularjs, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to work with Symfony2, Doctrine and Angujarjs. There is no problem with Symfony2 or Doctrine but I have issues using an ajax request with angularjs. Either it doesn't load anything and I did make a mistake while loading the json (json comes from Symfony and its working) or if it's working, but the json doesn't contain any of the relationship's data.

So, what's the correct way to
A: create a response for angularjs with relationship data (such as articles and categories)
B: load the requested json into an angularjs variable

Here is my controller.js

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []) .config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

}]);

app.filter('offset', function() {

    return function(input, start) {
        start = parseInt(start, 10);
        return input.slice(start);    
    };

});

app.filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {

    return function(text) {
        return String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
    };

});

app.controller("PaginationCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.articlesPerPage = 8;
    $scope.currentPage = 0;

        function htmlToPlaintext(text) {
            return String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
        }

    // this should load the json from '/admin/jsonallarticles' into the articles variable
    $http.get('/admin/jsonallarticles').success(function(data) {
        $scope.articles = data;
    });

    $scope.range = function() {
        var rangeSize = 5;
        var ret = [];
        var start;
        start = $scope.currentPage;

        if ( start > $scope.pageCount()-rangeSize ) {
            start = $scope.pageCount()-rangeSize+1;
        }

        for (var i=start; i<start+rangeSize; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }

        return ret;
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function() {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
        $scope.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    $scope.prevPageDisabled = function() {
        return $scope.currentPage === 0 ? "disabled" : "";
    };

    $scope.pageCount = function() {
        return Math.ceil($scope.articles.length/$scope.articlesPerPage)-1;
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function() {
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pageCount()) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    $scope.nextPageDisabled = function() {
        return $scope.currentPage === $scope.pageCount() ? "disabled" : "";
    };

    $scope.setPage = function(n) {
    $scope.currentPage = n;
    };

});
```

This is my symfony2 function

```
 public function jsonallarticlesAction() {

    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeBlogBundle:Articles');

    if ( !$articles ) {
         throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                 'Keine Beiträge gefunden!');
     }

   $queryArticles = $articles->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->where('a.status = :status')
            ->setParameter('status', 0)
            ->orderBy('a.createdDate', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);;

    $articles = array_values($queryArticles);   

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode($articles));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;

 }
```

**EDITED CONTROLLER**

I tried using the serializer which comes with Symfony

```
    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());

    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeBlogBundle:Articles')
            ->findAll();

    if ( !$articles ) {
         throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                 'Keine Artikel gefunden!');
     }

    $serializer->serialize($articles, 'json');
    return new Response(json_encode($json));
```

But I receive an error:

```
    A circular reference has been detected (configured limit: 1).
```

Comment: What do you see in your console response?

Comment: Can you also format your code please. I Just can't read the first part it's too messy.

Comment: I hope it is now better formatted, sorry I just copied it from a tutorial... [link](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/paginating-through-client-side-data.html)

Comment: I don't see anything in my console, because this is example is working. My biggest issue is the json response with missing relationship data...

Comment: Since you are getting an array result you must explicitly join your related entities.  Check the documentation for an example.  You will probably need to look at a serializer as well.  And use a JsonResponse  instead of Response.

Comment: I have tried using both Serializer and JMS Serializer but none of them work.. Please have a look at my updated controller

Answer (score 2):

For work with Angular.js you must write Rest API. For this you can use https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

And for serialize your entities with needed data use http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle

It compatible with FOSRestBundle.

As example of use those bundles you can look one our project https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/lost-and-found

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it was due to the fact that my Entity was related back to the same entity from my second entity on a different field.  I just simply created this function in my Entity:

```
public function removeRelationsThatCauseCircularError()
{
  $this->companyEvents = NULL;
}
```

And run the function before going through the serializer.